# Zend Framework create fully dynamic route while maintaining default routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

I understand how to create a simple custom route in the form of

```
example.com/archive/:year
```

However, I need to create a route in the form of

```
example.com/:make/:model
```

Both path components are variables. At the same time I want to keep the default Zend Framework routing. How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not for zend, but the technique is instructive and will probably work. I've struggled with this problem too, but was more for internationalisation.

http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/06/dynamic-routing-from-database-in-codeigniter/

Basically, you cache your routes into a file, and the framework matches them to your controller/variable details. I tried lots of things, complex regexes, and in the end, this worked out really, really well. Might be a good solution for you too.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a module based file architecture, you can maintain the zend framework default routes, and add custom routes for your modules.

for example

```
class Example_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

public function _initModuleRoutes()
{
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'modulename/:action/*',
        array(
                'module' => 'modulename',
                'controller' => 'modulecontroller',
                'action' => 'index'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('routename', $route);

    return $router;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce some condition i.e model is integer type or something else . Like this

```
 $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':make/:model',
    array(
        'controller' => 'car',
        'action'     => 'logic'
    ),
    array('make' => '\d+')
);
```

If you cannot distinguish them with extra condition like these  then how software gone do this for you weather its action name or make ?